# How I can re-add numbers inside dictionary while using multiprocessoring

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to build a program, which is using the multiprocessing. The overall task is to **sum numbers from 1, to 17. with using some sort of "levels"**

Here's some example:

```
            55       <- level 4

       36        19  <- level 3

   10      26    19  <- level 2

 3   7   11  15  19  <- level 1

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 <- level 0
```

As you can see, I want to add two adjacent numbers what is absolutely neccesary, it have to be done with multiprocessoring. I'm already done it to level 1. Now, I don't know how I may proceed with it, and here is question for you - since my processes are done, how I can loop it more to get it done on all levels? Here's some of my code:

I have dictionary

```
def divide_test(dict):
index = 0
print(len(starting_list))

for i in range(1, len(starting_list), 2):
    temporary = []

    temporary.append(starting_list[i - 1])
    temporary.append(starting_list[i])
    print(f"INDEX = {i}, S1 {starting_list[i - 1]}, S2 {starting_list[i]}")
    dict[index] = temporary
    index += 1

# Last index couldn't be added to rest of the numbers, so I have to save it for later usage.
if None in dict.values():
    last_key = next(reversed(dict.keys()))
    dict[last_key] = starting_list[-1]

print("\n\n\n")
for key, value in dict.items():
    print(f"KEY {key}, VALUE {value}")

return dict

Console output for code from above:
INDEX = 1, S1 1, S2 2
INDEX = 3, S1 3, S2 4
INDEX = 5, S1 5, S2 6
INDEX = 7, S1 7, S2 8
INDEX = 9, S1 9, S2 10
INDEX = 11, S1 11, S2 12
INDEX = 13, S1 13, S2 14
INDEX = 15, S1 15, S2 16
```

**function that calculate these numbers:**

```
def calculate(key, dict):
temporary = []

for values in dict[key]:
    temporary.append(values)
new_number = sum(temporary)
dict[key] = new_number
temporary.clear()
```

**Main**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
dictionary = manager.dict()

fill_starting_list()
# processes = how_many_processes()
append_lists_to_dictionary((len(starting_list) // 2), dictionary)
divide_test(dictionary)

processes = []
for process_index in range(len(starting_list) // 2):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=calculate, args=(process_index, dictionary))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

**Console output after processes are done:**

```
TEST {0: 3, 1: 7, 2: 11, 3: 15, 4: 19, 5: 23, 6: 27, 7: 31, 8: 17}
```

Comment: I hope that weird edit was an accident. Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is about making a lasting collection of Q/A pairs.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def fill_starting_list():
    starting_list = list(range(1, 18))
    print(f"Length {len(starting_list)} list {starting_list}")
    return starting_list

def calculate(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    numbers = fill_starting_list()
    print(f"Sum calculated by 'sum': {sum(numbers)}")
    while len(numbers) > 1:
        slices = (numbers[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2))
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            numbers = pool.map(calculate, slices)
            print(numbers)
    print(f"Sum calculated by recursive multiprocessing: {numbers[0]}")
```

Output:

```
Length 17 list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
Sum calculated by 'sum': 153
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 17]
[10, 26, 42, 58, 17]
[36, 100, 17]
[136, 17]
[153]
Sum calculated by recursive multiprocessing: 153
```

I'm using a process [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) in combinations with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) here, instead of individual process, because it is much easier.

As @FMc has pointed out, there's no need to use an extra function `caluculate`, just use `sum` (also removed the `fill_starting_list` function):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    numbers = list(range(1, 18))
    print(f"Length {len(numbers)} list {numbers}")
    print(f"Sum calculated by 'sum': {sum(numbers)}")
    while len(numbers) > 1:
        slices = (numbers[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2))
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            numbers = pool.map(sum, slices)
            print(numbers)
    print(f"Sum calculated by recursive multiprocessing: {numbers[0]}")
```

Comment: Could you please explain me this piece of code? slices = (numbers[i:i + 2]

Comment: @SlipperyBarrel It's a generator expression that produces length 2 slices of the `numbers` list. You could replace it with `slices = [numbers[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2)]` and then `print(slices)` to see it.

Comment: Good answer (+1). Small detail: `calculate()` isn't needed, since `pool.map(sum, slices)` will do the same thing.

Comment: @SlipperyBarrel I see you have unaccepted my answer. This is absolutely fine! But I'd be happy if you could clarify why. Maybe I can adjust the answer to make it better.